# the column value match error in php insert code

Tags: php

**addtomeal.php**

```
<?php
     $hostname="localhost";
     $username="root";
     $password="tiger";


     $dbhandle = \mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

$select= \mysqli_select_db($dbhandle,"sample")
     or mysqli_error($dbhandle);
 $itemId= \filter_input(\INPUT_GET,'itemId');

 $orderid= \filter_input(\INPUT_GET,'orderid');
 $subtitle= \filter_input(\INPUT_GET,'subtitle');
 $price= \filter_input(\INPUT_GET,'price');
 $quantity= \filter_input(\INPUT_POST,'quantity');
 $tnumber= \filter_input(\INPUT_GET,'tnumber');

 if(!empty(\filter_input(\INPUT_POST,'addtomeal')))
 {
  $sql="insert into addtomeal(orderid,itemId,subtitle,price,quantity,tnumber)values
 (NULL,'$orderid',$subtitle',$price','$quantity','$tnumber')";

/* @var $result type */
 $result= \mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql) or die(\mysqli_error($dbhandle));
}       

echo "success";
mysqli_close($dbhandle);
```

**items**

```
     <html>
     <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="display.css" >
     <title>Login Page</title>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1"> 

      </head>
      <body>


    <form name="customer" id='c1' method="post" action="cartdb.php">
   <script src="samcheck.js"></script>
    <div id="top">
        <?php session_start(); ?>

        <div id="toplbl">Welcome <?php  echo $_SESSION["name"]?></div>
        <?php session_start(); ?>
      <div id="toplbl1">This is Table Number <?php  echo $_SESSION["tnumber"]?></div>
    </div>

   <div id="d3"><?php echo "$descript1" ; ?> </div>     
    <div id="s3"><?php echo "$subtitle1" ;?> </div>  
    <div id="r3"><?php { echo "$price1" ;} ?> </div> 
    <div id='t3'><?php echo "$title1"; ?> </div>
    <label id="q1">Quantity</label>
    <input type='text' id='q' name='q' value='1'>
    <input type="hidden" name="itemId" value="<?php $itemId1 ?>">
    <input type ='button' name='plus' value='+' id='p' onclick="increase()">
    <input type='button' name='minus' value='-' id='m' onclick="decrease()">
    <input type='button' name='cancel' value='Cancel' id='cancel' onclick="location.href='customersvsoup.php'">
    <input type='submit' name='addtomeal' value='Add to my Meal' id='addtomeal'>


    <?php if($itemId==='oepd1007'){
    echo "<img src='getdesserticecreamimage.php?itemId=oepd1007' alt='image'> ";}
     ?>

    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm getting the error as Column count doesn't match value count at row 1. I have displayed all the values using echo statement from items.php to addtomeal.php, here im getting only the quantity. I have specified those in items.html page.

Answer (score 1):

You have a starting quote missing for both of these variables `$price'` and `$subtitle'`

```
(NULL,'$orderid', $subtitle', $price','$quantity','$tnumber')
                 ^ // there  ^ // there
```

change it to:

```
(NULL,'$orderid','$subtitle','$price','$quantity','$tnumber')
```

Comment: The more the merrier? hehe

Comment: thank you. i'm asking a further question.I have a tablecheck table where tnumber is the primary key,here it is the foreign key.so im getting the error as Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (sample.addtomeal, CONSTRAINT addtomeal_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (tnumber) REFERENCES tablecheck (tnumber) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: You're welcome. Have you, or can you remove the constraints to that column, or do you absolutely need it? @user3516005 I'm not well-versed enought with foreign keys, TBH.

Comment: Maybe you don't have a value that doesn't exist in one of your tables. @user3516005 I've researched it, but there are many different reasons this is happening.

Comment: but i have the value in the parent table

Comment: Like I said, I know nothing about foreign keys. @user3516005 - I suggest you post another question about it, and post your DB schema to go with it, along with the error message you're getting. Wish I could help you more.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are missing quotes in your query:

```
$sql = "insert into addtomeal (orderid, itemId, subtitle, price, quantity, tnumber) values
(NULL, '$orderid', '$subtitle', '$price', '$quantity', '$tnumber')";
```

I do not know the types of your fields, I placed the quotes for all the fields, but if the types are numerical you do not need to use quotes.

Comment: thank you. i'm asking a further question.I have a tablecheck table where tnumber is the primary key,here it is the foreign key.so im getting the error as Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sample`.`addtomeal`, CONSTRAINT `addtomeal_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`tnumber`) REFERENCES `tablecheck` (`tnumber`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: Do you get this error trying to insert a row to your `addtomeal` table? If so, it means that you have to add the row to your `tablecheck` first and then use the generated id to insert into the `addtomeal` table (in the `tnumber` field).

Comment: In this case you have to check the $tnumber value which is inserted in the `addtomeal` table. If it is number, remove the quotes. Echo the final $sql to check that all the values are correct.

Answer (score 0):

$sql = "INSERT INTO addtomeal (orderid, itemId, subtitle, price, quantity, tnumber) VALUES
('$orderid', '$itemid' ,'$subtitle', '$price', '$quantity', '$tnumber')";

Don't enter NULL from query enter NULL from default value from your table structure at the time of creating a table 
i guess u are missing $itemid in the query, I have added that in above query and also removed NULL

Comment: thank you. i'm asking a further question.I have a tablecheck table where tnumber is the primary key,here it is the foreign key.so im getting the error as Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (sample.addtomeal, CONSTRAINT addtomeal_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (tnumber) REFERENCES tablecheck (tnumber) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: Can u let me know which mysql Engine u are using

Comment: innodb is the mysql engine

Comment: InnoDB requires exactly the same data type in relations, 
so you cannot link an integer(11) to an integer(5) field 
also use unsigned integer as a data type 
please read below doc 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html